# How to segment data into N segments so that the sum of the segments' standard deviations are minimal?

Tags: optimization, algorithms

This sounds like a problem that must be commonly encountered but my search has not yielded anything meaningful.

I have a list of real numbers and I need to divide them into N segments. Each number must appear in exactly one segment. Segments cannot contain 0 numbers. The criterion for the optimization is the sum of standard deviations of each segment.

I am looking for either a formula, or an algorithm that could be applied to this problem.

EDIT: Data is sorted and segments must contain consecutive numbers.

Comment: Have you looked at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis

Comment: Are you looking for binning? See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binning-in-data-mining/

Comment: Are the segments required to contain consecutive members of the list?

Comment: The best I could find is a Jenks Natural Breaks method but the result it gives me are far away from the true solution (gotten by trying all combinations). 

Binning doesn't seem to achieve what I am trying to do.

The list will be initially sorted. After that, yes, they are.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this via dynamic programming, equivalently, as a shortest path problem in a directed acyclic network. If the list has length $n$, the node set is $(i,k)$ for $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ and $k\in\{1,\dots,N\}$. The arcs are from $(i,k)$ to $(j,k+1)$ with $i<j$ and cost $c_{i,j}$ equal to the standard deviation of items $\{i,\dots,j-1\}$. Now find a shortest path from the source $(1,1)$ to a dummy sink node that is accessible with zero cost from all $(j,N)$ nodes. The interpretation is that items $\{i,\dots,j-1\}$ form a segment if the corresponding arc is traversed.